# Binary logistic/logit regression on multilevel (hierarchical) data (in python)

Tags: regression, logistic, python, multilevel-analysis

I'm trying to run a binary logit regression on hierarchical data using python, and I cannot find a way to do that. Any help is appreciated.

The dataset has the following variables:

- Accuracy, the binary response variable
- Mask, the type of mask used, a categorical variable with 3 categories
- Position, where on the screen the stimulus is presented, categorical with 3 categories
- RT, reaction time, a metric variable
- subjectID, the grouping variable, because it is repeated measure

Currently, I am trying to use statsmodels:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
md = smf.logit("Accuracy ~ Mask * RT + Position", data, groups = "subjectID")
```

Unfortunately, `smf.logit()` does not account for multilevel data and will just ignore the `groups = "subjectID"`, giving a `ValueWarning: unknown kwargs ['groups']`.

I have also tried using `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` but as far as I'm aware, that doesn't accept categorical independent variables.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you so much.